# Error creating scratch org in Azure Pipeline

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, format, azure, pipelines

I'm stuck in the same error for a long time.
I have a template pipeline that creates a scratch org and do more things.

I have another pipeline that uses the template and passes it some parameters:

This is how I send the parameters, note that I have spaces in the package parameter:

```
extends:
  template: template.yml@templates
  parameters:
    package: My Personal Package
```

In the template, I use the package parameter here:

```
variables:
  - name: orgname
    value: $[format('{0}/{1}', '${{ parameters.package }}', variables['Build.SourceBranchName'])]
```

With this, I have the variable `orgname` with a value like this:

```
My Package Number/my_branch
```

The problem is when I try to use this variable orgname to create a scratch org:

```
cmd="sfdx force:org:create --targetdevhubusername DevHub --wait 10 --durationdays 1 --definitionfile ${{ parameters.scratchOrgFile }} orgName="$(orgname)" --setdefaultusername --setalias BuildOrg --json" && (echo $cmd >&2)
```

The problem is with the variable `orgname`, I try it with:

```
orgName=\"$(orgname)\"

orgName='$(orgname)'
```

And more, but always I have an error with this variable.

I receive errors like:

```
Personal: command not found
"Error in the following argument\nPersonal\nSet varargs with this format: key=value or key=\"value with spaces\"
```

I send the cmd value to error output, and I see the command:

```
sfdx force:org:create --targetdevhubusername DevHub --wait 10 --durationdays 1 --definitionfile config/scratch-orgs/base-scratch-def.json orgName="My Personal Package/my_branch" --setdefaultusername --setalias BuildOrg --json
```

I don't know where is the problem, because if I run the same command as before in my local project, it works correctly.

Thanks